# Tracking Celery job progress in main

Tags: python, celery

I am launching a bunch of tasks in celery:

```
jobs = [some_task.delay(*arg) for arg in args]
results = jobs.get()
```

Is there some way of continously outputting the number of tasks completed from the main thread or otherwise, ie:

```
while tasks_still_running:
    print "Completed %s of %s tasks." % (num_complete, len(jobs))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery signals for this:

```
from celery.signals import task_success
@task_success.connect()
def tasks_success_callback(signal, result, sender):
    print result
```